# System says memory controller not available and doesn't boot?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, irq

Recently I have had a MainBoard-problem. I've send my mainboard to service and today I got it back from the company. It is a Foxconn 520a mainboard. Now I have installed my exchanged mainboard. But now I have a problem. My system boots until the device list with IRQ entries appear. The system says `"Verifying DMI-pool-data..."` and nothing happens. The IRQ-device list shows that the memory-controller is not available. All other devices have got an IRQ.

```
Bus No.  Device No.  Func No.  Vendor/Device   Class   Device Class       IRQ
0        0           0         10DE 0547       0500    Memory Controller  NA
```

Do you have any ideas where the problem could be? I already have disconnected all unnecessary devices like the hard disks.

Perhaps it is a BIOS problem, but I don't know where I should look.

Would be nice if there is any advice,

Greetings,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return it and say that it still doesn't work.

First, if you can get into the BIOS, do a full restore / settings reset. After this, if you are still having problems - This sounds like a hardware issue and unless you fancy soldering, repairing will simply be more trouble than its worth.

If you haven't done anything to it (e.g. careless installation), I would say that this is a hardware issue when you got it.

RMA returns usually do not get you a new board but a refurbished one, and it is possible that it has an error that they did not know about.

Comment: Thanks I think I will take it back to service. Should be the best way, even if i always wait more than 6 weeks until it will return.

Answer (score 0):

If you have disconnected all devices, and are booting with just the CPU and memory installed, there is not much more you can try -- other than swapping memory to see if it is bad memory.

I *have* seen bad memory cause some very bizarre problems, so that is worth trying, if you can.